# C# Constructor chaining: proper usage?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, constructor

New to C# and looking at constructor chaining.

I have the following class:

```
class ConstructorChaining
{
    public string a;
    public string b;
    public int c;

    public ConstructorChaining(string astring, string anotherstring, int anint)
    {
        a = astring;
        b = anotherstring;
        c = anint;
    }

    public ConstructorChaining(string astring) : this("fff", astring, 2)
    {
        a = astring;
    }
}
```

If I instantiate it thus, and output the values of the fields:

```
ConstructorChaining cc2 = new ConstructorChaining("xyz");
Console.WriteLine(cc2.a);
Console.WriteLine(cc2.b);
Console.WriteLine(cc2.c);
```

Why does cc2.a have the value "xyz", not "fff"? I would have thought that only cc2.**b** would get this value.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you set `a = astring` *after* calling the other constructor, so the value is overwritten.

Answer (score 3):

The "chained" constructor is executed before the body of the constructor.

So, first it assigns `"fff"` to `a` in the constructor with three parameters.
After that constructor has finished executing, the body of the constructor with one parameter is executed and assigns `"xyz"` to `a`.

The following would be a sensible implementation of chained constructors:

```
class ConstructorChaining
{
    public string a;
    public string b;
    public int c;

    public ConstructorChaining(string astring, string anotherstring, int anint)
    {
        a = astring;
        b = anotherstring;
        c = anint;
    }

    public ConstructorChaining(string astring) : this(astring, astring, 2)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this("fff", astring, 2)
```

runs before your xyz constructor.
So cc2.a has the valye fff and then you overwrite it with xyz

```
class ConstructorChaining
{
    public string a;
    public string b;
    public int c;

    public ConstructorChaining(string astring, string anotherstring, int anint)
    {
        a = astring;
        b = anotherstring;
        c = anint;
    }

    public ConstructorChaining(string astring) : this("fff", astring, 2)
    {
        //This code will be executed After your 3 param constructor. 
        a = astring;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the 3-parameter constructor is executed before the body of the 1-parameter constructor executes.

In pseudo-code it looks like this:

```
public ConstructorChaining(string astring) 
{
    this("fff", astring, 2)
    a = astring;
}
```

**Not** like this:

```
public ConstructorChaining(string astring) 
{
    a = astring;
    this("fff", astring, 2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your running the implementation in the constructor after the call of the super class constructor, so you override cc2.a to be "xyz".
At the end the steps done are as follows:

```
a = astring;        // = fff
b = anotherstring;  // = xyz
c = anint;          // = 2
a = astring;        // = xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the constructor with one parameter (that you call) sets 
a = "fff"
b = "xyz"
c = 2
this is done by the constructor with the 3 parameters. And after that the one-parameter-contructor sets a = "xyz"